# Зависает приложение ios на swift

Tags: ios, swift

Здравствуйте. Прошу помочь с кодом. Приложение для ios вылетает с ошибкой
**Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range**

Вот код в котором это происходит

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cat", for: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell

    let data = self.categoryData[indexPath.row]

    //code...

    return cell
}
```

Ругается на строку let data = self.categoryData[indexPath.row]
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Так зависает или вылетает? Ответ простой: `self.categoryData` содержит меньше элементов чем строк в `TableView`.

Comment: Вылетает. Спасибо за ответ. Буду разбираться

Comment: Количество элементов совпадает, но в определенный момент теряется self.categoryData - массив пустой

Comment: Вот, уже ясно что к чему. Теперь забудьте что падает, правильно делает, так и должно быть. Ищите почему данные исчезают.

Comment: спасибо. благодаря Вам нашел ошибку.